# Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later Flutter iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook, dart, authentication

I am working on facebook authentication for a flutter project. App works out of the box on `Android` but on iOS, throws following error in safari.

[image]

Translation in english is: `Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later`.

There are many similar issues but all are on `Android`, not on `iOS`.

Following is `flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-arm, locale en-PK)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
  Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
✗ Android license status unknown.
  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more 
    details.
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
    [✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I am using `flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.7`. A reminder, facebook login is working fine on `Android`, issue is on `iOS` only.

Thanks

Comment: Quoting from your question "There are many similar issues but all are on Android, not on iOS." but in other places you say that you have issues on iOS, not android. I suggest to review the question

Comment: @PrzemysławSamsel you can see it is an iOS device screenshot, not Android and also I have fixed it by now

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan im running into this issue as well for some of the Android devices, but not on iOS, wondering how did you get this fixed? Thanks a lot

Comment: @gazcn007 I had to change the permissions from Facebook app

Comment: Gotcha thank you Muhammad! Will give it a try today :)